# Short hand delete many getElementById in javascript

Tags: javascript

How do i short hand this code?

```
document.getElementById('bl7').remove();
document.getElementById('bl8').remove();
document.getElementById('bl9').remove();
document.getElementById('bl10').remove();
document.getElementById('bl11').remove();
document.getElementById('bl12').remove();
document.getElementById('bl13').remove();
document.getElementById('bl14').remove();
document.getElementById('bl15').remove();
document.getElementById('bl16').remove();
document.getElementById('bl17').remove();
document.getElementById('bl18').remove();
document.getElementById('bl19').remove();
```

i can't use jquery thank you.

Comment: I thought we only have `removeChild`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.remove()` on a DOM element is a very new and experimental method (not supported in any version of IE, for example).  You would probably be better off using `.removeChild()`.

If you wanted to remove that many elements, I'd suggest you use a table and iterate through the table or if they are truly sequential ID values, you can manufacture the ids in a loop.

```
var item;
for (var i = 7; i <= 19; i++) {
    item = document.getElementById("bl" + i);
    item.parentNode.removeChild(item);
}
```

---

If you needed to do this frequently, then it may be easier to put a class name on all the objects that you want to operate on at once and get all of them in a query based on class name with something like `document.querySelectorAll()`.

Or, you could create any number of short functions for operating on a set of ids:

```
function removeElements(idArray) {
    var item;
    for (var i = 0; i < idArray.length; i++) {
        item = document.getElementById(idArray[i]);
        if (item) {
            item.parentNode.removeChild(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Node.remove()` is relatively new: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode.remove

Comment: @FelixKling - good point.  I've modified my answer in light of that info.

Comment: Thank you, i just added the missing semicolon.